# SLF4J error: This version of SLF4J requires log4j version 1.2.12 or later

Tags: spring, log4j, websphere, slf4j

When I am trying to deploy the application on Websphere 7.0 I get the error message on console

0000000d SystemErr     R SLF4J: This version of SLF4J requires log4j version 1.2.12 or later. See also http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#log4j_version

Further when spring internally calling log4j api, following error occurs:

0000000d webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp notifyServletContextCreated SRVE0283E: Exception caught while initializing context: {0} 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'processEngine' defined in ServletContext resource

[/WEB-INF/spring_config/jbpm_applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed;

nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: 
Factory method [public org.jbpm.api.ProcessEngine org.jbpm.pvm.internal.processengine.SpringHelper.createProcessEngine()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/apache/log4j/Logger.trace(Ljava/lang/Object;)V

I upgraded the log4j api from 1.2.16 to 1.2.17 but still i got the same error.
Additionally, slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar and slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar are being used in classpath.

Comment: Either you have a wrong version of log4j or you have more than one log4j on your classpath: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?69777-NoSuchMethodError-for-org-apache-log4j-Logger-log

Comment: Version is right and I checked there is no other log4j jar in classpath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should switch classloading policy for your application to "parent last". Then the version of log4j bundled with your application will be used. Please see [Class loader settings](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/urun_rclassloader_inst.html) for details.